# Getting Parse Error while installing apk file in Device

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Created default  "Welcome to Xamrine Forms" application with Cross Plate Form in xamarine using visual stuidio 2017 and i generated .apk file by clicking on achieve and i also signed a key, and i copied this .apk file to Samsung device through USB Cable, i have been trying to fix this issue since 4 days by searching other stackoverflow Questions but unable to fix that, these are my setting in release mode

[image: Application Manifest Settings]

[image: Android Options Settings]

[image: Build Settings]

[image: Parse Error]

Comment: Did you try to install the app through visual studio in your phone?

Comment: no but after i got the .apk file  i copied it to device and then i tried to install it in device.

Comment: try to install app through visual studio with usb debugging enabled for your phone

Comment: so can't we install directly by copying the apk file into our device because i need to share this file with my client

Comment: What is the android version of your device? Have you tried other device?